# Split list in a data frame as binary variables in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dataframe

I have a column of lists in a data frame. I am trying to split the list to variables in the data set.

For example, I have a data set whose columns are like

```
V1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
V2 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
V3 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
V4 <- list(list("a","b","c"),
        list("a","b","d"),
        list("b","c","d"),
        list("a","b","e"),
        list("b","c","e"))
V5 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
sample<-NA
sample <- data.frame(V1,V2,V3,I(V4),V5)
```

In this, `v4` contains a column of lists

After splitting the list, the desirable data frame should be as below

```
> sample
  V1 V2 V3      V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1  1  1  1 a, b, c  1  1  1  1  0   0
2  2  2  2 a, b, d  2  1  1  0  0   1
3  3  3  3 b, c, d  3  0  1  1  1   0
4  4  4  4 a, b, e  4  1  1  0  0   1
5  5  5  5 b, c, e  5  0  1  1  0   1
```

data in the new variable created should be 1 or 0 if it is available in the respective list.

Here is my approach for doing the same, First I identified all the unique elements of the list and created respective columns with NA's and then trying to check if the particular variable is in the list then it is assigned 1 else 0.

```
features <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
l <-1
for(j in 1:length(sample$V4)){
  for(k in 6:10){
    for(i in features){
      if( i  %in% tolower(unlist(sample$V4[[j]]))){
        sample[j,k] <-1
        print(sample[j,k])
      }else{
        sample[j,k] <-0
      }
      print(c(l,k,i,j))
      l <- l+1

    }
  }

}
```

I don't know where this is going wrong, it is giving result as below

```
> sample
  V1 V2 V3      V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1  1  1  1 a, b, c  1  0  0  0  0   0
2  2  2  2 a, b, d  2  0  0  0  0   0
3  3  3  3 b, c, d  3  0  0  0  0   0
4  4  4  4 a, b, e  4  1  1  1  1   1
5  5  5  5 b, c, e  5  1  1  1  1   1
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output for others to debug your problem

Comment: @akrun Thanks! edited with the reproducible code.

Comment: It is not clear how you got those values 1 in the expected output when the elements are not present.  For example `b, c, e  5  0  0  0  1   1`

Comment: @akrun Corrected! 
Seems its really a very bad day for me.

Comment: @akrun It would be helpful If you can tell me how to rename the columns with the respective item like "a","b", "c", "d","e"

Comment: Actually, the `mtabulate(sample$V4)` comes with the columnnames you mentioned.  you can just do `sample1 <- cbind(sample, mtabulate(sample$V4))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mtabulate` from `qdapTools`

```
library(qdapTools)
sample[paste0("V", 6:10)] <-  mtabulate(sample$V4)
```

Comment: Perfect!! 
Thank you so much